# Using stringsim in stringdist

Tags: r, string, fuzzy-comparison, stringdist

I'm using the package stringdist to compare some vectors of strings but I keep getting a different answer than what I think I should when I try to test out the package.

I want to do this:

```
stringsim('PANDIAN', 'PANIAN', method="lv")
[1] 0.8571429
```

To 2 columns in a dataframe

```
stringsim(testdf.lv$Last[1], testdf.lv$matchedname[1], method="lv")
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("lengths") : 
  no applicable method for 'lengths' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

I need to be able to do this because ideally, I would replace the row numbers with an i and run it in a loop. Is this even possible? I tried looking for similar errors but the other questions were not very helpful.

Comment: You really should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that defines `testdf.lv` otherwise we have no idea what's in it. However it sounds like you have factors rather than character variables. Try `stringsim(as.chracter(testdf.lv$Last[1]), as.character(testdf.lv$matchedname[1]), method="lv")`

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, you are right. I should have included the full code. And YES! It was because the testdf.lv column was a vector instead of a character. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @MrFlick. It turns out the data I was using in the column:

```
testdf.lv$Last
```

Was mistakenly characterized as a factor variable instead of character. Changing the that column to a character with the following:

```
testdf.ld$Last <- as.character(testdf.ld$Last)
```

Fixed the error and I was able to rewrite the code into a for loop to go through the entire dataframe.